# I developed a portal using salesforce lightning. In Desktop view having lot of options, but Not in IPAD view. Why?

Tags: lightning, tab, list-button, portal, ipad

I developed a portal using salesforce lightning. In Desktop view having lot of options, but Not in IPAD view. Why? Can you please help me

Please check the difference of IPAD View and Desktop View below screenshots

IPAD View:
[image]

Desktop View:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many limitations for the salesforce1 app in compared to the browser version of Salesforce i.e. Lightning Experience.

In the context of your question, here are some limitation:-

1. [Create a listview Chart in Lightning Experience is available but not in the  Mobile app](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews_listview_chart_create_lex.htm&type=5)
2. [Add Kanban List Views is available in Lightning Experience but not in the app](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSPIQA4)
3. [Salesforce1 Should Show All List Views in the Salesforce1 App](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ky69AAA)
4. [Find the Data You Need in a Jiffy with List View Search is not available in the app](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lex_search_lists.htm)

According to Salesforce, Have a look on list view action available:-

[image]

Reference:- [List Item Actions in the Salesforce Mobile App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actionbar_list_item_actions_overview.htm&type=5)